# What is the integral of $e^{(-a/b)}$?

Tags: integration

I have a quick question:

> What is the integral of $e^{-(a/b)}$ with respect to the variable $a$?

Am I correct in thinking it is $-be^{-(a/b)}$?

Thanks.

Comment: With respect to which variable?

Comment: I edited my question. It is with respect to the variable a.

Comment: Well $e^{-\frac ab} = (e^{-\frac 1b})^a$ so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention which variable you were talking about.

$-be^{-(a/b)}$ would be an antiderivative of $e^{-(a/b)}$  with respect to $a$

Comment: Ok that's what I thought. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please consider closing the question if you are satisfied by the answer by clicking the grey ✓.